# Sci-fi movie in which horses were rare and going extinct and being sold on the black market

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember the name of this movie I wanted to watch from the last four years. I remember something about horses being important to the story. It seems like they were going extinct and extremely rare and were sold on the black market, or maybe that's totally off the mark, I have no idea, lol. I just remember from the trailer, it looked like a sort of cerebral story and maybe there was some romance in it?

Comment: Probably a long shot, but could it be *The Postman*? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119925/